# Unity not loading project if internet is enabled

Tags: unity-game-engine

My computer crashed and since then it has not been opening properly Unity Editor and my projects

Since i have updated unity several times i decided it was time to make a fresh instalation so i uninstalled Unity and Visual Studio, deleted all the unity folders on AppData, and Program Files, then i reinstalled unity 2018.2.5 and Visual Studio

but for some reason it wont load any project nor it will create any new project if my internet connection is enabled, i need to disconnect my computer, launch my unity project, wait for it to load then re enable my internet connection

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Regards...

Comment: Is it giving you an error message when failing to load?

Comment: Nope, no error at all it shows all the unity proceses running on the task manager but i cant kill them unless i shutdown internet or restart my computer

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely related to licensing. I recommend checking out Unity's documentation on [managing your license](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagingYourUnityLicense.html).

For starters, try the following once you have Unity running:

1. Click the Unity drop-down on your toolbar (Help on Windows OS).
2. Click the Manage License option.
3. Select "Check for Updates."

You can also try the "Active New License" option.

Comment: Is not the licensing because as I told, i made a fresh installation and unity welcome screen shows fine but it wont load any project

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this that worked for me is to uninstall and reinstall unity hub, then create a new project and then try to open it. It should work then.